# How to regenerate a token if it contains "+" ? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I create token to use it in another function. If token contains "+", I want to regenerate token until it hasn't any "+". How can I do it?

**Token Function**

```
fun createSignature3(data: String, secret: String):String{
    val sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
    val secret_key = SecretKeySpec(secret.toByteArray(), "HmacSHA256")
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key)
    val token = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.toByteArray()))
    return token
}
```

**Function that use token**

```
fun makeOrder(){
    generateOdemeInfo()
    odemeStateAl(merchant_oid)
    val token = createSignature3(hash_str+merchant_salt,merchant_key)
    if (token.contains("+")){
        // do what?
    } else {

        
        oDao.makeOrder(
            cc_owner,card_number,expiry_month,expiry_year,cvv,
            merchant_id,user_ip,merchant_oid,email,
            payment_type,payment_amount,request_exp_date,currency,test_mode,non_3d,merchant_ok_url,
            merchant_fail_url,user_name,user_address,user_phone,
            basket,debug_on,client_lang,token,non3d_test_fail,installment_count,"bonus"
        ).enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                htmlStringRepo.value = response.body()!!.string()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {}
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to get rid of ```+```? If your ```token``` from ```createSignature3()``` is different every time, you can have a simple ```while (condition) { token = createSignature3() } ``` loop to do it.

Comment: Yes, my api not accept `+`. When I use that loop, it runs forever and not out of loop. Is there a way to do them it synchronized?

Comment: May I know do you get a different ```token``` if you re-run your Application? i.e., is there any way to refresh your ```hash_str``` or ```merchant_salt``` in the ```while``` loop? Or is it possible to switch using Base64Url instead?

Comment: You was right! I forgot to refresh `hash_str`. After I refresh it and put it in while loop, it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate token in while loop solve the problem.

```
        while (token.contains("+")){
        generatePaymentInfo(user_ip)
        token = createSignature3(hash_str+merchant_salt,merchant_key)
    }
```